# Running Kivy on Linux xfce (chromebook) yields only black screen

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, kivy, xfce

somewhat new to Linux. Just set up a "dual boot" to XFCE ubuntu on my Chromebook. Installed Kivy and tried to set up the basic "Hello World" program.

Upon running the program from the terminal, I get either a black screen or a graphical glitch of whatever else is going on, on the desktop.

The terminal also displays a list of debug lines (I'm not used to this in Windows. Assuming this is standard.)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfIQ0.png  Here's what I'm looking at.

.py file

```
from kivy.app import App


class WeatherApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WeatherApp().run()
```

.kv file

```
Label:
   text: "Hello World!"
```

Called from terminal with

```
python main.py
```

Am I doing something wrong?