# Black / transparent screen with kivy on chromebook

Tags: ubuntu, kivy, chromebook, crouton-os

When trying to run a simple hello world program, kivy will show either a black or a transparent (a visual copy of everything underneath) screen. Using Ubuntu 14.04 on Acer Chromebook C740. Similar to this [Running Kivy on Linux xfce (chromebook) yields only black screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34665792/running-kivy-on-linux-xfce-chromebook-yields-only-black-screen), but with crouton instead of dual boot and Ubuntu instead of xfce.

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/wxv/.kivy/logs/kivy_16-03-23_0.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.lang> with limit=None, timeout=None
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.image> with limit=None, timeout=60
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.atlas> with limit=None, timeout=None
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.texture> with limit=1000, timeout=60
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.shader> with limit=1000, timeout=3600
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[DEBUG  ] [App         ] Loading kv <./my.kv>
[DEBUG  ] [App         ] kv <./my.kv> not found
[DEBUG  ] [Window      ] Ignored <egl_rpi> (import error)
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <3.0 Mesa 10.1.3>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Intel Open Source Technology Center>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Mesa DRI Intel(R) Broadwell >
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <1.30>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[DEBUG  ] [Shader      ] Fragment compiled successfully
[DEBUG  ] [Shader      ] Vertex compiled successfully
[DEBUG  ] [ImageSDL2   ] Load </usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/data/glsl/default.png>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/share/fonts/truetype> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/share/fonts/truetype/unfonts-core> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/share/fonts/truetype/wqy> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/share/fonts/truetype/droid> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/local/share/fonts> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/data/fonts> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Base        ] Create provider from mouse
[DEBUG  ] [Base        ] Create provider from probesysfs
[DEBUG  ] [ProbeSysfs  ] using probesysfs!
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[DEBUG  ] [Atlas       ] Load </usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/data/../data/images/defaulttheme.atlas>
[DEBUG  ] [Atlas       ] Need to load 1 images
[DEBUG  ] [Atlas       ] Load </usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/data/../data/images/defaulttheme-0.png>
[DEBUG  ] [ImageSDL2   ] Load </usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/data/../data/images/defaulttheme-0.png>
```